# Using Scaffold Form to Embed SoundCloud Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, soundcloud

I'm trying to create a form in an app that takes a song's title, artist and soundcloud embed link so that these can be used in a post.

I created a `scaffold`, and `set soundcloudembed:text`

I added a link `<%= post.soundcloudembed %>` at the position where I want the embedded player to be displayed. This link does not work.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: Give us an example of the data that you are storing in `soundcloudembed` field.

Comment: Hi! It is just the soundcloud iframe. `<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/192408098&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>` @loqman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `soundcloadembed` field contains html tags you should tell rails to output raw data using one of these two methods:

```
<%== post.soundcloudembed %>

<%= post.soundcloudembed.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The answer worked! Thanks again.